# Solving linear inhomogenous ODE when inhomogenous part is not linearly independent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider solving the following inhomogenous linear ODE using the method of undetermined coefficients:

$y'(x)-y(x)=e^x$

Since $e^x$ is a solution to the associated homogenous equation, it can't be a particular solution to the inhomogenous equation. In this situation, I'm supposed to make an ansatz of the form $xe^x$ instead, but how come? It's easy to verify that this solves the problem, but why is this assumption justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular solution to this equation is unique, because of this anything goes so long as you can get at the answer.

You know your solution needs to be linearly independent of $e^x$. The simplest function you could guess is $x * e^x$ so basically just try the simplest assumption and hope it works out. In your DE class you probably have a list of "appropriate" ansatz for different circumstances. In real problems you sometimes have to just do a lot of well informed guessing until you find something that works. Learning how to make good guesses is a skill that is hard to develope.

The important thing is that the uniqueness of the solution means that it doesn't matter *how* you get the solution. You can pull it out of a magicians hat if you want. If it solves the DE it is **the** solution and that is all the justification that is necessary.

---

Here is another way you might have guessed the solution that is less of a guess,

Instead of supposiong you have $xe^x$ suppose you have $A(x) e^x$ where $A(x)$ is some unknown function. Since $A(x)$ can be any function we aren't really making any assumptions about the form of the solution, what we are doing is leveraging the fact that the differential equation "likes" $e^x$.

Substitute the ansatz into the DE:

$$ \left(A'(x)e^x + A(x)e^x \right)- \left(A(x)e^x \right) = e^x $$

$$ A'(x)e^x  = e^x $$

$$ A'(x)  = 1 $$

So $A(x) = x+C$.

Comment: I should also point out that the DE you proposed can be solved by alternative means (e.g. Laplace transforms). So you don't always have to guess to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: The solution method in the second part is an example of the "variation of parameters" approach.

Comment: 'The important thing is that the uniqueness of the solution means that it doesn't matter how you get the solution. You can pull it out of a magicians hat if you want. If it solves the DE it is the solution and that is all the justification that is necessary'. Wise words, too often unspoken.

Comment: I'm aware that there are alternate methods, and that a solution is a solution regardless of where it came from. What I want to know is why this ansatz is reasonable, i.e., if I didn't already know that it would solve the problem, how would I have known to make this assumption? What is the logic behind multiplying the inhomogeneous side by a power of $x$ to obtain a new ansatz?

If I understand correctly, it has to do with finding a linearly independent solution, and multiplying by a power of $x$ just happens to be a simple way to do so.

Comment: I addressed this in my answer but perhaps I didn't emphasize it enough. The motivation is to get a function that is *linearly independent* of the homogeneous solution. The simplest way to construct such a function is to multiply the old function by $x$.

Comment: I also want to point out that you should make a point of remembering useful ansatz. I can't tell you how many stubborn differential equations I solved just trying a random ansatz that was useful in the past.